# javascript having same method with different implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having js file (rework.js) with function below

```
/**
 * Java script functions to set comments for selected rework reason.
 */
function setReworkCheckFields() {
    var note = $("#rework_note").val();
    var reworknoteImage = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_image");
    var reworknoteScript = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_script");
    var reworknoteVoice = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_voice");
    var reworknoteMusic = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_music");
    if ($(reworknoteImage).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_image_note").val(note);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteScript).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_script_note").val(note);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteVoice).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_voice_note").val(note);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteMusic).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_music_note").val(note);
    }
}
```

and i have imported this js file in html and i have added same method with different implementaiton as below in html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='style/js/rework.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function setReworkCheckFields() {
    var note = $("#rework_note").val();
    var reworknoteImage = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_image");
    var reworknoteScript = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_script");
    var reworknoteVoice = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_voice");
    var reworknoteMusic = document.getElementsByName("reworknote_music");
    if ($(reworknoteImage).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_image_note").val(note);
    } else {
        $("#reworknote_image_note").val(null);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteScript).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_script_note").val(note);
    } else {
        $("#reworknote_script_note").val(null);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteVoice).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_voice_note").val(note);
    } else {
        $("#reworknote_voice_note").val(null);
    }
    if ($(reworknoteMusic).is(':checked')) {
        $("#reworknote_music_note").val(note);
    } else {
        $("#reworknote_music_note").val(null);
    }
}
</script>
```

and calling the javascript function below.

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>Image: <input type="checkbox" name="reworknote_image" ${reworknote_image.workingchecked} onchange="setReworkCheckFields()"/></td>
         <td>Script: <input type="checkbox" name="reworknote_script" ${reworknote_script.workingchecked} onchange="setReworkCheckFields()"/></td>
         <td>Voice: <input type="checkbox" name="reworknote_voice" ${reworknote_voice.workingchecked} onchange="setReworkCheckFields()"/></td>
         <td>Music: <input type="checkbox" name="reworknote_music" ${reworknote_music.workingchecked} onchange="setReworkCheckFields()"/></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

can some one how the flow will work. does this valid to write ?

Comment: I might be mistaking, but i believe the second function will overwrite the one in rework.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the flow is that only the last function is defined in the js scope cause it's override any js code with similar name.

In javascript there is no function overload like in Java or other langs.
You can wrap your code to different namespaces though:

```
var MyFirstNameSpace = {
    setReworkCheckFields: function(){
         // code goes here...
    } 
};

var MySecondNameSpace = {
    setReworkCheckFields: function(){
         // code goes here...
    } 
};
```

then you can call either MyFirstNameSpace.setReworkCheckFields() or MySecondNameSpace.setReworkCheckFields();

In general note it's not good practice to override the javascript global scope because you don't know what other js code your project will include and that will mess up with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Second function will redeclare first one, so when you call `setReworkCheckFields()` you will run second function.

And yes, its valid. Its just like you overriding a variable.

Remember, if you'll declare this function one more time in code, it will also redeclare this definition. It's usefull behavior in some cases, but you have to be carrefull with redeclaring js functions.